# Is it possible to use the DeviceCode authentication Flow with Azure Java SDK?

Tags: java, azure, azure-sdk

I successfully generate an `IAuthenticationResult` using the azure `msal4j`library - I am presented with a device code, and when that code is typed into a browser, it shows the correct scopes / permissions,
and now I'd like to take this authentication result and pass it into the Azure-SDK authentication similar to:

```
    val result = DeviceCodeFlow.acquireTokenDeviceCode()


    val a: Azure = Azure.configure()
        .withLogLevel(LogLevel.BODY_AND_HEADERS)
        .authenticate(AzureCliCredentials.create(result))
        .withDefaultSubscription()
```

Does anyone know where to look / or any samples which do this?

Comment: If it is useful for you, could you please accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `msal4j` library to get access token, then use the token to manage Azure resource with Azure management SDK, please refer to the following code

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String subscriptionId = ""; // the subscription id
        String domain="";// Azure AD tenant domain 
        DeviceCodeTokenCredentials tokencred = new DeviceCodeTokenCredentials(AzureEnvironment.AZURE,domain);
         Azure azure =Azure.configure()
                           .withLogLevel(LogLevel.BASIC)
                           .authenticate(tokencred)
                           .withSubscription(subscriptionId);
                                  
         for(AppServicePlan plan : azure.appServices().appServicePlans().list()) {
                  
                  System.out.println(plan.name());
                  
                  }
    }  
}

// define a class to extend AzureTokenCredentials
 class DeviceCodeTokenCredentials extends AzureTokenCredentials{

    public DeviceCodeTokenCredentials(AzureEnvironment environment, String domain) {
        super(environment, domain);
    }

    @Override
    public String getToken(String resource) throws IOException {
        // use msal4j to get access token 
        String clientId="d8aa570a-68b3-4283-adbe-a1ad3c1dfd8d";// you Azure AD application app id
        String AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/";
        Set<String> SCOPE = Collections.singleton("https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation");
        PublicClientApplication pca = PublicClientApplication.builder(clientId)
                .authority(AUTHORITY)
                .build();

        Consumer<DeviceCode> deviceCodeConsumer = (DeviceCode deviceCode) ->
        System.out.println(deviceCode.message());

      DeviceCodeFlowParameters parameters =
        DeviceCodeFlowParameters
                .builder(SCOPE, deviceCodeConsumer)
                .build();
      IAuthenticationResult result = pca.acquireToken(parameters).join();       
      return result.accessToken();
    } 
 }
```

[image]

Comment: thanks Jim, I have successfully been able to use this snippet to authenticate. 

I was wondering if you know if any other samples similar to this? Because now I have successfully authenticated - I am having issues where some Resources are not on the management.azure endpoint, but rather on the Storage / Graph endpoints and I need to try obtain a token with permissions for these endpoints.